# Authenticating methods inside Identityserver3 project

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

I am creating a Token managemenet service using **Thinktecture Identityserver3**. I made quite a good progress on it and have a few clients which are succesfully using this service.

My Question is i have some webapi methods related to **Password and User management** in my Token management service which also has Identityserver3 integrated. I know how to authenticate Web apis which are in other projects but not sure how to authenticated the web apis which are inside the project.

I tried putting `[Authorize]` on these web apis but no luck.  Am i not supposed to put any of these web apis inside token management project ? I am sure there must be a way to authenticate these inner web apis ?

please help.

Comment: What do you mean with - how to authenticated the web apis which are inside the project?

Comment: I have few web api methods inside the identity server core project. That means both have same host address as they both are under the same project (Visual Studio). I am not sure how i can authenticate these webapi methods ?

Comment: Do you extend some IdentityServer's features in the core project? Or do you have an instance of the IdentityServer in the solution where you have a web api?

Comment: I have extended the IDserv3 features in my core project . I have my own Client, Scope, User Store and Token handles. I also have my own web api methods for User operations such as change password, reset, register user, external logins etc. I want to access these apis from other clients. Not sure how to authenticate this webapis.

Comment: I can recommend to use something like this: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20Authentication - not directly change the features of Identity Server but use the following solution. There is MVC application which is running on the same url like the IdentityServer but if you want to call the web api you have to be authentificated. It's probable more flexible that change the identityserver core.